# Different git branches in Rstudio projects

Tags: r, git, rstudio

Can Rstudio be configured to work with different git branches in different Rstudio projects?

Comment: You can select a branch in the "git" panel and I believe this information is stored in the project settings by RStudio.

Comment: Thanks @Roland I'll try and let you know